# Google BigQuery table Patch/Update doesn't work

Tags: php, google-bigquery

```
Google_Http_Request object {
  batchHeaders => array(3) (
    [Content-Type] => (string) application/http
    [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => (string) binary
    [MIME-Version] => (string) 1.0
  )
  queryParams => array(0)
  requestMethod => (string) PATCH
  requestHeaders => array(3) (
    [content-type] => (string) application/json; charset=UTF-8
    [authorization] => (string) *edited*
    [accept-encoding] => (string) gzip
  )
  baseComponent => (string) https://www.googleapis.com
  path => (string) /bigquery/v2/projects/aerobic-forge-504/datasets/wr_dev/tables/user_profile
  postBody => (string) [{"name":"user_id","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"is_complete","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"country_id","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"state","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"city","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"zip","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"language","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"industry_id","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"subscribed_status","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"tracking_prod_type","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"tracking_prod_id","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"timestamp","type":"timestamp","mode":"required"},{"name":"tags","type":"string","mode":"repeated"},{"name":"utm","type":"record","mode":"nullable","fields":[{"name":"source","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"medium","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"campaign","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"content","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"term","type":"string","mode":"nullable"}]},{"name":"meta","type":"string","mode":"nullable"}]
  userAgent => (string) Client_Library_Examples google-api-php-client/1.0.3-beta (gzip)
  canGzip => (bool) true
  responseHttpCode => null
  responseHeaders => null
  responseBody => null
  expectedClass => (string) Google_Service_Bigquery_Table
  accessKey => null
}
```

I had this call, it returns successful but the required changes are not reflected on the schema. `tracking_prod_type` is a new field, and it's not added to the schema. We tried `Patch` and the `Update` way, and we can't add the additional columns. The update returns: `Provided Schema does not match`. Patch returns valid.

On the postBody, we tried different syntax's and none of them works. `[etag] => (string) "wRHWmN_1J7FEq2j8vIkltiyoyRw/GVGxfUY15UK1iZLhzZzfWOf-1Ow"`

We tried following this Q&A [Bigquery add columns to table schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702420/bigquery-add-columns-to-table-schema)

We see the Last Modified field get modified on the table schema, when we issue the call, but the structure doesn't have the new columns.

**updated**

```
Google_Http_Request object {
  batchHeaders => array(3) (
    [Content-Type] => (string) application/http
    [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => (string) binary
    [MIME-Version] => (string) 1.0
  )
  queryParams => array(0)
  requestMethod => (string) PATCH
  requestHeaders => array(2) (
    [content-type] => (string) application/json; charset=UTF-8
    [authorization] => (string) edited
  )
  baseComponent => (string) https://www.googleapis.com
  path => (string) /bigquery/v2/projects/aerobic-forge-504/datasets/wr_dev/tables/user_profile
  postBody => (string) {"fields":[{"name":"user_id","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"is_complete","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"country_id","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"state","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"city","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"zip","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"language","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"industry_id","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"subscribed_status","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"timestamp","type":"timestamp","mode":"required"},{"name":"tags","type":"string","mode":"repeated"},{"name":"utm","type":"record","mode":"nullable","fields":[{"name":"source","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"medium","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"campaign","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"content","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"term","type":"string","mode":"nullable"}]},{"name":"meta","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"tracking_prod_type","type":"string","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"tracking_prod_id","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"}]}
  userAgent => null
  canGzip => null
  responseHttpCode => nu...
```

**update2 using PATCH**

This is when I have tableResource and schema, and using PATCH. Two additional columns listed in the schema. And I've got: `Provided Schema does not match Table aerobic-forge-504:wr_dev.user_profile`

```
Google_Http_Request object {
  batchHeaders => array(3) (
    [Content-Type] => (string) application/http
    [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => (string) binary
    [MIME-Version] => (string) 1.0
  )
  queryParams => array(0)
  requestMethod => (string) PATCH
  requestHeaders => array(3) (
    [content-type] => (string) application/json; charset=UTF-8
    [authorization] => (string) edited
    [accept-encoding] => (string) gzip
  )
  baseComponent => (string) https://www.googleapis.com
  path => (string) /bigquery/v2/projects/aerobic-forge-504/datasets/wr_dev/tables/user_profile
  postBody => (string) {"tableReference":{"datasetId":"wr_dev","projectId":"aerobic-forge-504","tableId":"user_profile"},"schema":{"fields":[{"name":"user_id","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"is_complete","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"country_id","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"...
```

**update3 using PUT**

When using the update node I still get `Provided Schema does not match Table aerobic-forge-504:wr_dev.user_profile`

```
Google_Http_Request object {
  batchHeaders => array(3) (
    [Content-Type] => (string) application/http
    [Content-Transfer-Encoding] => (string) binary
    [MIME-Version] => (string) 1.0
  )
  queryParams => array(0)
  requestMethod => (string) PUT
  requestHeaders => array(4) (
    [content-type] => (string) application/json; charset=UTF-8
    [authorization] => (string) edited
    [accept-encoding] => (string) gzip
    [content-length] => (int) 1221
  )
  baseComponent => (string) https://www.googleapis.com
  path => (string) /bigquery/v2/projects/aerobic-forge-504/datasets/wr_dev/tables/user_profile
  postBody => (string) {"tableReference":{"datasetId":"wr_dev","projectId":"aerobic-forge-504","tableId":"user_profile"},"schema":{"fields":[{"name":"user_id","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"is_complete","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"name":"country_id","type":"integer","mode":"nullable"},{"...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When calling patch or update, you need to provide something that looks like a table. In your example above, it looks like you're not passing a table resource, just the fields inside the table resource. You may need to wrap your postBody in something like `{"schema": {"fields": postBody } }`

This is a little bit confusing from the other question, because bq update does this wrapping for you.

The reason you're seeing update fail is because the bigquery server doesn't see any schema at all, so it thinks you're trying to delete the schema. And patch succeeds but does nothing, because it doesn't see any valid fields at all, so it just does a null patch operation.

Here is an example of a curl session that adds fields to a schema. It should be relatively easy to adapt to php. It uses auth.py from [here](https://code.google.com/p/bigquery-e2e/source/browse/samples/ch05/auth.py)

```
PROJECT_ID=<your_project_here>
DATASET_ID=scratch

BASE_URL=https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects
TABLES_URL=${BASE_URL}/${PROJECT_ID}/datasets/${DATASET_ID}/tables

### Make a scratch dataset.
bq --project_id=${PROJECT_ID} mk –d ${DATASET_ID}

SCHEMA="{'fields': [{'name':'foo', 'type': 'STRING'}]}"
TABLE_REF="{'tableId': 'table1', \
    'datasetId': 'scratch', \
    'projectId': '${PROJECT_ID}'}"

### Make a temporary table with a schema.
curl -H "$(python auth.py)" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X POST \
    -d "{'tableReference': ${TABLE_REF}, \
         'schema': ${SCHEMA}}" \
    "${TABLES_URL}"

### Tables.update()
SCHEMA2="{'fields': [ \
    {'name':'foo', 'type': 'STRING'}, \
    {'name': 'bar', 'type': 'FLOAT'}]}"
TABLE_JSON="{'tableReference': ${TABLE_REF}, 'schema': ${SCHEMA2}}"
curl -H "$(python auth.py)" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X PUT \
    -d "${TABLE_JSON}" \
    "${TABLES_URL}/table1"

### Tables.patch()
EXPIRATION_TIME=$(($(date +"%s")+24*60*60))000
curl -H "$(python auth.py)" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -X PATCH \
    --data-binary "{'expirationTime': '${EXPIRATION_TIME}'}" \
    "${TABLES_URL}/table1"
```

Comment: I've tried that too, and it's silent. I will post more update.

Comment: A couple of other things: 1. order is important. If you change the ordering, it will look like an incompatible schema. 2. you cannot add a required field to an existing schema.

Comment: By ordering do you mean, I can add new fields to the end of the table only? What options do I have on the old columns?

Comment: On the other hand using the official PHP Api from github: I'v got this when changed from table to schema: Catchable fatal error: Argument 4 passed to Google_Service_Bigquery_Tables_Resource::patch() must be an instance of Google_Service_Bigquery_Table, instance of Google_Service_Bigquery_TableSchema given

Comment: I've updated the question, still doesn't work after the postBody change. See `[etag] => (string) "wRHWmN_1J7FEq2j8vIkltiyoyRw/MCVd1PYApiH5Gae-WwhG1ra6WCU"`

Comment: Yes, you can only add new fields at the end of the table. On the old columns, you have the option to change required to nullable.

Comment: It looks like you dropped the 'created' field. I'll file a bug on improving the error message.

Comment: Hi Jordan Tigani, I there any way to update the schema in the given order? Right now I have a problem that I can't merge two table with different schema.