# How to Add new column dynamically to already existed table in bigquery..?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I created a csv file with three columns in a row..in google bigquery in created a dataset with one table with csv file ....for this i completed my java code...but now i have to add a new column to existed row dynamically in java code..?

```
// Main method for data print.
@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    // Create a new BigQuery client authorized via OAuth 2.0 protocol
    Bigquery bigquery = createAuthorizedClient();
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    row.set("Column1", "Sample23");
    row.set("Column2", 7);
    row.set("Column3", "Sample25");
    TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows rows = new TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows();
    rows.setJson(row);
    List rowList = new ArrayList();
    rowList.add(rows);
    TableDataInsertAllRequest content = 
        new TableDataInsertAllRequest().setRows(rowList);
    TableDataInsertAllResponse response = bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(PROJECT_ID, DATASET_ID, TABLE_ID, content).execute();
    System.out.println("Final response = " + response);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two table operations [Update](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/update) and [Patch](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/patch).

You need to use the **Update** command, to add new columns to your schema.

Important side notes:

1. order is important. If you change the ordering, it will look like an incompatible schema.
2. you can only add new fields at the end of the table. On the old columns, you have the option to change required to nullable.
3. you cannot add a required field to an existing schema.
4. you cannot remove old fields, once a table's schema has been specified you cannot change it without first deleting all the of the data associated with it. If you want to change a table's schema, you must specify a writeDisposition of WRITE_TRUNCATE. For more information, see the Jobs resource.

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914630/google-bigquery-table-patch-update-doesnt-work) of a curl session that adds fields to a schema. It should be relatively easy to adapt to Java. It uses auth.py from [here](https://code.google.com/p/bigquery-e2e/source/browse/samples/ch05/auth.py)

When using Table.Update(), you must include the full table schema again. If you don't provide an exact matching schema you can get: `Provided Schema does not match Table`. For example I didn't paid attention to details and in one of my update calls I didn't include an old field like `created` and it failed.

Comment: actuvally i didnot use any jobs in my java code..simply i created a dataset with one table with a row in three columns...now i have to add new column at java code not in csv file.. i am posting my complete source code..

Comment: @duozmo added the link

Answer (score -1):

Actually I didn't use any jobs in my java code. I simply created a dataset with one table with a row in three columns. Now I have to add new column at java code not in csv file. I am posting my complete source code:

```
public class BigQueryJavaGettingStarted {


    // Define required variables.
    private static final String PROJECT_ID = "nvjsnsb";
    private static final String DATASET_ID = "nvjjvv";
    private static final String TABLE_ID = "sampledata";
    private static final String CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION = "client_secrets.json";
    static GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = loadClientSecrets(CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION);
    // Static variables for API scope, callback URI, and HTTP/JSON functions
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(BigqueryScopes.BIGQUERY);
    private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "https://www.example.com/oauth2callback";
    // Global instances of HTTP transport and JSON factory objects.
    private static final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();
    private static GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = null;


    // Main method for data print.
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            // Create a new BigQuery client authorized via OAuth 2.0 protocol
            Bigquery bigquery = createAuthorizedClient();
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            row.set("Column1", "OneMoreCol1");
            row.set("Column2", 79);
            row.set("Column3", "OneMoreCol2");
            TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows rows = new TableDataInsertAllRequest.Rows();
            rows.setJson(row);
            List rowList = new ArrayList();
            rowList.add(rows);
            TableDataInsertAllRequest content = new TableDataInsertAllRequest().setRows(rowList);
            TableDataInsertAllResponse response = bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(PROJECT_ID, DATASET_ID, TABLE_ID, content).execute();
            System.out.println("Final response = " + response);

        }


    // Create Authorized client.
    public static Bigquery createAuthorizedClient() throws IOException {

        String authorizeUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(
                clientSecrets,
                REDIRECT_URI,
                SCOPES).setState("").build();

        System.out.println("Paste this URL into a web browser to authorize BigQuery Access:\n" + authorizeUrl);

        System.out.println("... and type the code you received here: ");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String authorizationCode = in.readLine();

        // Exchange the auth code for an access token and refresh token
        Credential credential = exchangeCode(authorizationCode);

        return new Bigquery(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential);

    }


    // Exchange code method.
    static Credential exchangeCode(String authorizationCode) throws IOException {

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = getFlow();
        GoogleTokenResponse response =
            flow.newTokenRequest(authorizationCode).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
        return flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, null);

    }


    // Get flow.
    static GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow getFlow() {

        if (flow == null) {
            HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
            JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
            flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(httpTransport,
                    jsonFactory,
                    clientSecrets,
                    SCOPES)
                .setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("force").build();
        }
        return flow;

    }


    // Load client secrets.
    private static GoogleClientSecrets loadClientSecrets(String clientSecretsLocation) {
        try {
            clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(new JacksonFactory(),
                    new InputStreamReader(BigQueryJavaGettingStarted.class.getResourceAsStream(clientSecretsLocation)));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Could not load client_secrets.json");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return clientSecrets;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post answer, you can edit your original question, and make sure you do something. In your code I don't see any reference for the update call. Also please understand we won't write the code for you, we will provide you solutions.