# Update column type in a table from Boolean to string

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to update an empty column from type Boolean to string in big-query. 
How can i do it without overwrite the table and load all the data?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only add new fields at the end of the table. On the old columns, you have the option to change required to nullable. So what you want is not possible, only if you add a new field, or as you say completely overwriting the table.

There are two table operations [Update](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/update) and [Patch](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables/patch).

You need to use the **Update** command, to add new columns to your schema.

Important side notes:

1. order is important. If you change the ordering, it will look like an incompatible schema.
2. you can only add new fields at the end of the table. On the old columns, you have the option to change required to nullable.
3. you cannot add a required field to an existing schema.
4. you cannot remove old fields, once a table's schema has been specified you cannot change it without first deleting all the of the data associated with it. If you want to change a table's schema, you must specify a writeDisposition of WRITE_TRUNCATE. For more information, see the Jobs resource.

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914630/google-bigquery-table-patch-update-doesnt-work) of a curl session that adds fields to a schema. It should be relatively easy to adapt to Java. It uses auth.py from [here](https://code.google.com/p/bigquery-e2e/source/browse/samples/ch05/auth.py)

When using Table.Update(), you must include the full table schema again. If you don't provide an exact matching schema you can get: `Provided Schema does not match Table`. For example I didn't paid attention to details and in one of my update calls I didn't include an old field like `created` and it failed.