# Getting an "Invalid schema update. Cannot add fields" from BQ, with ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION set in the configuration

Tags: python, google-bigquery

The following python code snippet produces the error in the title:

```
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
# Set the destination table
table_ref = client.dataset(args.bq_dataset_id).table(args.bq_cum_table)
job_config.destination = table_ref
job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'
job_config.schemaUpdateOptions = ['ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION', 'ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION']

# Start the query, passing in the extra configuration.
query_job = client.query(
    sqlstr,
    # Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query
    # and of the destination table.
    location="US",
    job_config=job_config,
)  # API request - starts the query

query_job.result()  # Wait for the query to finish
```

I'm working from the "Writing query results to a destination table" [here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/usage/queries.html), but with the additional 'ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION' and 'ALLOW_FIELD_RELAXATION' config settings to (I thought) enable adding additional columns to the target table.
The schema of the data which I am trying to append probably is not a superset of the schema of the target table. And I have no control over the order of items resulting from the query, in case either if those considerations matter.

I'm using standard SQL. The query is like:

SELECT
`StudyDate`,
`SeriesDate`,
`AcquisitionDate`
FROM `project.dataset.table`
LIMIT 1

This is my first use of the BQ Python library so I won't be surprised if I've overlooked something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You are doing it right except for one little mistake.

`job_config.schemaUpdateOptions` is a field that doesn’t exist in the [BigQuery Python API](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/bigquery/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig.html#google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJobConfig.schema_update_options). Change it for `job_config.schema_update_options` and your code will work as expected.

Also, [here are several examples](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas) showing how to modify the BigQuery table schema using Python.

Comment: Thanks @llompalles. That did it.

Comment: I had found the schemaUpdateOptions property by (erroneously) looking at the REST API reference, and Python didn't complain when I used that as a property of the job_config object.

Comment: @bcli4d Could you mark the answer with the green tick so I will be more visible and thus able to help people like I did with you? Thank you in advance

Comment: after adding schema_update_options in code still getting below error. Any suggestion will be helpful:  How to get blank column removed while loading csv files into Bigquery table. I am getting below error while loading.
 Cannot add fields (field: string_field_0)

Comment: The above answer is correct-
`job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",)
 job_config.schema_update_options = ['ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION']`