# Custom date format for loading data into BigQuery, using bq?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm uploading a CSV file to Google BigQuery using `bq load` on the command line. It's working great, but I've got a question about converting timestamps on the fly.

In my source data, my timestamps are formatted as `YYYYMM`, e.g. `201303` meaning March 2013.

However, Google BigQuery's [timestamp fields](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery?hl=en#datatypes) are documented as only supporting Unix timestamps and `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format strings. So unsurprisingly, when I load the data, these fields don't convert to the correct date.

Is there any way I can convey to BigQuery that these are `YYYYMM` strings?

If not I can convert them before loading, but I have about 1TB of source data, so I'm keen to avoid that if possible :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another alternative is to load this field as STRING, and convert it to TIMESTAMP inside BigQuery itself, copying the data into another table (and deleting the original one afterwards), and doing the following transformation:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP(your_ts_str + "01") AS ts
```

Comment: That looks promising! Do you know if it's possible to add that as a new column in BigQuery?

Comment: Looks like this is the way to add new columns: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16704021/194000

Comment: Just to understand if this answer does what I need - do you know if it's possible to insert the converted timestamp value into the new column in BigQuery?

Comment: This answer assumes that you will create new table by issuing SELECT and choosing new name for destination table, and probably also setting AllowLargeResults=true

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Mosha's answer can be achieved by:

`SELECT DATE(CONCAT(your_ts_str, "01")) as ts`