# How to use a join function in BigQuery in order to copy the data to an updated schema?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

As currently we can not change the schema of a table in big query, we would like to create a new table with the updated schema and copy over the data.
My question is how to correctly use a join function to move the existing data from the old to the new table, assuming we added a number of new columns.

Thank you

Comment: In the BigQuery API, you can run the query and save it as a table.  A `join` isn't needed.

Comment: You are able to add new columns to the schema. You need to create new table only if you want to drop some columns or reorganize the table. Let us know more specific what you want to achieve to be able to help you better with your case.

Comment: Example of adding columns to an existing table here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702420/bigquery-add-columns-to-table-schema