# Google BigQuery: how to create a new column with SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to add an column to an already existing table without using legacy SQL.

The basic SQL syntax for this is:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD column_name datatype;
```

I formatted the query for Google BigQuery:

```
ALTER TABLE `projectID.datasetID.fooTable`
ADD (barColumn date);
```

But than the syntax is incorrect with this error:

```
Error: Syntax error: Expected "." or keyword SET but got identifier "ADD" at [1:63]
```

So how do I format the SQL properly for Google BigQuery?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Support for `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN` was released on 2020-10-14 per [BigQuery Release Notes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/release-notes#October_14_2020).

So the statement as originally proposed should now work with minimal modification:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `projectID.datasetID.fooTable`
ADD COLUMN barColumn DATE;
```

Comment: I recommend that this be changed to the accepted answer as the updated release notes include this functionality and the above example does work.

Answer (score 9):

BigQuery does not support `ALTER TABLE` or other DDL statements, but you could consider [submitting a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0). For now, you either need to open in the table in the BigQuery UI and then add the column with the "Add New Field" button, or if you are using the API, you can use [tables.update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702420/bigquery-add-columns-to-table-schema/16704021).

Comment: Instructions for adding columns with the API can be found on the page [Modifying table schemas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas).

Answer (score 3):

my_old_table

a,b,c
1,2,3
2,3,4

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_dataset.my_new_table    
AS    
SELECT a,b,c,     
"my_string" AS d, current_timestamp() as timestamp     
FROM my_dataset.my_old_table
```

my_new_table

a,b,c,d,timestamp
1,2,3,my_string,2020-04-22 17:09:42.987987 UTC
2,3,4,my_string,2020-04-22 17:09:42.987987 UTC

schema:
a: integer
b: integer
c: integer
d: string
timestamp: timestamp

I hope all is clear :)
With this you can easily add new columns to an existing table, and also specify the data types. After that you can delete the old table, if necessary. :)

Comment: Copying the whole table just to add a column works but is a bit of an overkill. In the end, bigquery is a column storage so adding an extra column should be very easy. However the lack of an alter-table statement makes this solution a nice workaround.

Comment: I like your answer but I having just one query. What to do if I want my_new_table to look like following one?

my_new_table

a,b,c,d,timestamp
1,2,3,my_string_1,2020-04-22 17:09:42.987987 UTC
2,3,4,my_string_2,2020-04-23 12:24:29.437447 UTC


I want different data not the same one as you added in your. Please help what to do?

Comment: The same data I added, i.e. "my_string" and time stamp is just dummy, it has to be replaced with the actual values. In your case you need to do a merge statement after creating then new columns. However you also need a unique identifier as well in the old table. I hope this helps. (I hope you are familiar with bq sql syntax  MERGE... target_table USING source_table ON condition WHEN MATCHED THEN ..... )