# Adding a column from an existing BQ table to another BQ table using Python

Tags: python, sql, datatable, google-bigquery

I am trying to experiment with creating new tables from existing BQ tables, all within python. So far I've successfully created the table using some similar code, but now I want to add another column to it from another table - which I have not been successful with. I think the problem comes somewhere within my SQL code.

Basically what I want here is to add another column named "ip_address" and put all the info from another table into that column.

I've tried splitting up the two SQL statements and running them separately, I've tried many different combinations of the commands (taking our CHAR, adding (32) after, combining all into one statement, etc.), and still I run into problems.

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery


def alter(client, sql_alter, job_config, table_id):
    query_job = client.query(sql_alter, job_config=job_config)
    query_job.result()
    print(f'Query results appended to table {table_id}')


def main():

    client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json('my_json')
    table_id = 'ref.datasetid.tableid'

    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()

    sql_alter = """
        ALTER TABLE `ref.datasetid.tableid`
        ADD COLUMN ip_address CHAR;
        INSERT INTO `ref.datasetid.tableid` ip_address
        SELECT ip
        FROM `ref.datasetid.table2id`;
    """

    alter(client, sql_alter, job_config, table_id)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

With this code, the current error is "400 Syntax error: Unexpected extra token INSERT at [4:9]" Also, do I have to continuously reference my table with `ref.datasetid.tableid` or can I write just tableid? I've run into errors before it gets there so I'm still not sure. Still a beginner so help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BigQuery does not support `ALTER TABLE` or other DDL statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44131248/google-bigquery-how-to-create-a-new-column-with-sql/44134493#44134493), take a look into how [Modifying table schemas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas#adding_a_column_when_you_overwrite_or_append_data) there you can find an example of how to add a new column when you append data to a table during a load job.