# Adding new columns to Schema of BigQuery Table in Java

Tags: java, google-bigquery, schema, updates, patch

I am looking for ways to update Schema of an existing table in BigQuery. I could see doing the same in python [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas) which is an API Request. I wanted to see this in Java and going through documentation and source code I could find

```
TableDefinition tableDefinition = StandardTableDefinition.of(schema);
table.toBuilder().setDefinition(definition)
```

But it rewrites the whole schema. Other possible of ways of updating schema can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702420/bigquery-add-columns-to-table-schema)

Can someone guide me regarding adding new columns to existing table in BigQuery using Java ?

Comment: Have a look here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1564 You need to specify the entire schema again -including your new cols.

Comment: @GrahamPolley could you please add your response as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in [this](http://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1564) github issue. You need to specify the entire schema again -including your new cols.